# Replacing a line within a text file

Tags: python, list, file, replace, line

Basically what I want to do is simply overwrite a line from a text file holding scores, though i haven't had any luck after searching around for awhile

I'm confused on how to replace 'val' which contains the old list, to 'empty', and in essence update the file 'scores.txt' so that the line is replaced

```
index = 0
with open('scores.txt','r') as f:
    x = f.readlines()
    print(x)

    name = input('Enter name: ')
    print('\n')

    c_1 = 0
    c_2 = 0
    empty = []

    for val in x:
        c_1 += 1
        print("Iteration",c_1)
        print('val',val)

        if name in val:
            print('True: ' + '"' + name + '"' , val)
            empty.append(val)

            empty = [i.split() for i in empty]
            print(empty)

            empty = [item for sublist in empty for item in sublist]
            print(empty,'\n')

            print('len empty',len(empty))

            while len(empty) > 4:
                del empty[1]
                c_2 += 1
                print("Del Iteration",c_2)

            print('empty after del',empty)

            break


        elif name not in val:
            print("False\n")
        index+=1
```

This is what can be seen inside 'scores.txt'

```
jill 9 10 7 8 5
bob 4 6 7
denas 2 4
john 1
```

My goal with this is to have the scores of 'jill' to be cut down to only 3, which my code does, but then save this so after exiting the code and opening 'scores.txt' the change can be seen

I know this question has been answered before, but I couldn't get it to work for myself, as I am still new to Python :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you need to write to a separate file and then copy the new file over the old file to do this. (you can use [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) or [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) to seemingly modify the file in place, but you can research these yourself)

As an example, given:

```
$ cat /tmp/scores.txt
jill 9 10 7 8 5
bob 4 6 7
denas 2 4
john 1
```

You can modify the file this way:

```
with open('/tmp/scores.txt', 'r') as f, open('/tmp/mod_scores.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('jill'):
            line=' '.join(line.split()[0:4])
        fout.write(line.strip()+"\n")
```

Now you have a file with your desired modifications:

```
$ cat /tmp/mod_scores.txt
jill 9 10 7
bob 4 6 7
denas 2 4
john 1
```

Now just copy the new file on top of the old file and you are done. To copy, use [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) to now have the file `scores.txt` to seemingly be modified in place.

---

From the comment, to get the last 3 vs the first 3 scores, you would do:

```
with open('/tmp/scores.txt', 'r') as f, open('/tmp/mod_scores.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('jill'):
            li=line.split()
            line=' '.join([li[0]]+li[-3:])
        fout.write(line.strip()+"\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution which worked, sorry to bug you but how could I change this so that it deletes the values left to right?

Comment: See edit. Use a slice and add the two lists together.

Answer (score 1):

And just in case (dwag's answer is what you should use) here is your code working after some fixes:

```
index = 0
# empty and x must have global scope.
empty = []
x = []

with open('scores.txt','r') as f:

    x = f.readlines()
    name = input("Enter the name: ")
    c_1 = 0
    c_2 = 0
    for val in x:
        c_1 += 1
        print("Iteration",c_1)
        print('val',val)

        if name in val:
            empty.append(val)
            empty = [i.split() for i in empty]
            empty = [item for sublist in empty for item in sublist]

            while len(empty) > 4:
                del empty[1]
                c_2 += 1
            break

        elif name not in val:
            print("False")

        index += 1

with open('scores.txt','w') as f:
    x[0] = ' '.join(empty + ['\n'])
    f.writelines(x)
```